# Is the AccessibleContext really a Java Object reference?

Tags: java

I am able to use WindowsAccessBridge.dll to get access to java window (SwingSet2), and use the dll methods to interact with the controls.
I can iterate the tree (of java controls) using code shown [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/5463279),  and get information from the controls,
and I can do actions like SetText in Text box, or send click action to a button etc.

However, I am finding that the accessibility contexts are not consistent:
The SetText method works perfectly when I use the accessibility context got from the 'setMousePressedFP' method of the dll, after clicking on the text box.

However, I cant use the accessibility context got by iterating the control tree when trying to set text in a text box, although I verified that the other information e.g. size and other properties of the text box is same.

From [this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/api.htm):

> "The functions GetAccessibleContextAt and
>   GetAccessibleContextWithFocus retrieve an AccessibleContext object,
>   which is a magic cookie (really a Java Object reference) to an
>   Accessible object and a JVM cookie. "

However, the accessibility context differs everytime I click on the text box (without restarting the java program). The vmID matches eveytime.
If the AccessibleContext is really a Java Object reference, shouldnt I get the same AccessibleContext number everytime I click on the same control (without restarting the java window) ? and shouldnt that AccessibleContext number also be available in the tree?

Worst part is that the settext method doesnt work when I use the AccessibleContext got from iterating the control tree.

**Edit to clarify the question further:**

I am clicking on the same text box, so I would expect the windowsaccessdll function to return reference to the same control. As a long value the accessibeContext is different everytime I click, but its ok as the SetText method works everytime with the different long values and I can see the new text set in the text box.
 The problem is when I iterate the control tree and the accessibility context got from the tree iteration doesnt work for the SetText method.
More specifically - how does the AccessibleContext compare to a c pointer - the c pointer would always be same when I get it for a specific control. The AccessibleContext appears to be a 8 digit long value that is different by few tens or hundreds based on where the mouse is clicked inside the text box.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you call a method that returns an object reference you'll be getting an object reference. Unless it's a primitive there is nothing else in Java. It is never stated that the method always returns a reference to the same object.

Comment: I am clicking on the same text box, so I would expect it to return reference to the same control. As a long value the accessibeContext is different everytime I click, but its ok as the SetText method works everytime with the different long values and I can see the new text set in the text box.
 The problem is when I iterate the control tree and the accessibility context got from the tree iteration doesnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by "as a long value"? Also I'm just realizing now that this is not a Java API but C++. So it will of course not return a Java Object reference but a C++ object reference.